# Nested Iframe with pointer-events style property

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to add an iframe containing a button to pop up a window chat.
It looks as follow:

```html
<iframe
  id="chatSession"
  src="http://localhost:4200/chat-export"
  name="chat"
  style="
    display: inline-block !important;
    border: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    pointer-events: none;
  "
  frameborder="0"
  scrolling="yes"
  allowtransparency="true"
></iframe>
```

The content of http://localhost:4200/chat-export is also the following (The chat logic is implemented in another project, I want to be able to use this chat on any page):

```html
<iframe
  id="chatWidget"
  src="http://localhost:4200/session/new?agentId=4HORORmF1i1gd1WVzaxC&agentName=Agente"
  name="ChatBot"
  scrolling="No"
  style="pointer-events: auto;"
></iframe>
<a id="chatButton" class="floatChat" (click)="controlShow()">
  <i class="fa fa-comment-o my-floatChat" style="pointer-events: auto;"></i>
</a>
```

As you can see on the first iframe, I set the property pointer-events: none, because I want the background not to stop me from scrolling, but only the button and the window, like the following  image:
[This is the main idea of how I want it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJsaD.jpg)
The problem is that when pointer-events are none, the nested iframe I'm using, even though I set pointer-events:auto doesn't detect any click on the screen.

In conclusion, how can  I manage nested Iframes to work as follows:

```
parent Iframe (pointer-events: none) {

 child iframe (pointer-events:auto ) 

}
```

Comment: Since you've already turned off pointer events in the first level iframe, all pointer events coming from inside of it (including the nested iframe) will be swallowed up.

Comment: So you are saying that the child iframe pointer-event  property will be ignored?.. Is there another method I could accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not saying that it will be ignored, but it is simply overridden. What you're trying to do here is exactly the same as what you'd experience if you set `opacity: 0` on the parent iframe: do you think the content of the nested iframe will show up, even if you set it to `opacity: 1`?

Comment: Moreover, this feels like an XY problem: why would `pointer-events: none` cause the background to stop you from scrolling? What are you trying to achieve here? It's also not clear in your screenshot which part is the parent iframe, and which part is the child iframe.